# Test comparison doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, angularjs-e2e

1) I have the very strange mistake in my protractor code. And I don't understand what may be reason of it.

```
it('should filtering by interval correctly', function () {
    filter_field.click();
    var filter_field_text = filter_field.element(by.css('input'));

    var exist_value1 = element(by.xpath('//tr[@data-row-index="1"]/td[@data-column-index="5"]/div')).getText().then(function (value) {
        var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
        return (floatValue);
    });
    var exist_value2 = element(by.xpath('//tr[@data-row-index="1"]/td[@data-column-index="5"]/div')).getText().then(function (value) {
        var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
        return Math.round(floatValue) + 1;
    });
    filter_field_text.sendKeys(exist_value1);
    filter_field_text.sendKeys('-');
    filter_field_text.sendKeys(exist_value2);
    browser.sleep(3000);
    var filtered_values = element.all(by.xpath('//tr/td[@data-column-index="5"]/div'));
    filtered_values.each(function (element, index) {
        var current_value = element.getText().then(function (value) {
            var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
            return (floatValue);
        });
        expect(exist_value1 <= current_value).toBe(true);
    });
    if (true) console.log("Test done!");
});
```

I have wrong result: 'Expected false to be true'
Although, absolutely similar code working fine:

```
it('should filtering by one-sided < interval correctly', function () {
    filter_field.click();
    var filter_field_text = filter_field.element(by.css('input'));
    var exist_value = element(by.xpath('//tr[@data-row-index="1"]/td[@data-column-index="5"]/div')).getText().then(function (value) {
        var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
        return (floatValue);
    });
    filter_field_text.sendKeys("<");
    filter_field_text.sendKeys(exist_value);
    browser.sleep(3000);
    var filtered_values = element.all(by.xpath('//tr/td[@data-column-index="5"]/div'));
    filtered_values.each(function (element, index) {
        var current_value = element.getText().then(function (value) {
            var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
            return (floatValue);
        });
        expect(exist_value <= current_value).toBe(true);
    });
    if (true) console.log("Test done!");
});
```

2) Also I have a question about complex expectations. Can I do something like:

```
expect(exist_value1 >= current_value & exist_value2 <= current_value).toBe(true);
```

In my tests it isn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&&` instead of `&` in your second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found the answer for my question.
If somebody have the same problem: comparison should be in the function, because it is a js method.

Here is the right code:

```
it('should sorting by interval correctly', function () {
filter_field.click();

if (column_body.get(0).isPresent()) {
  var exist_value1 = column_body.get(0).getText().then(function (value) {
    var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
    return (floatValue);
  });
  var exist_value2 = column_body.get(0).getText().then(function (value) {
    var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
    return Math.round(floatValue) + 1;
  });
  filter_field.sendKeys(exist_value1);
  filter_field.sendKeys('-');
  filter_field.sendKeys(exist_value2);
  var filtered_values = element.all(by.xpath(column_body_xpath));

  filtered_values.each(function (element) {
    var current_value = element.getText().then(function (value) {
      var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
      expect((exist_value1 <= floatValue) && (exist_value2 >= floatValue)).toBeTruthy();  //INTO SCOPES!!!
    });
  });
}
else {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
}

console.log("ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec_8");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print all these values before the expect statement? The float value might be different if they are getting derived through some calculation. Use `parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2)` to get the float value till 2 decimal places.

Comment: Yes, I print it before except, and I don't see mistakes. And, unfortunately, your method didn't helped me. What interesting is that in another tests comparison working without problems.

Comment: the I think the problem is here-
`var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
        return Math.round(floatValue) + 1;` you should return parseFloat of `Math.round(floatValue)`. Math.round returns an Integer.